# Does Orange data mining software has multi-layer perceptron classification?

Tags: classification, orange, mining, multi-layer

I have IRIS like data set. I want to run few (3-4) classification 
techniques to see which classifier work best for my biological data.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Orange 3 does not seem to implement any kind of ANN yet. However, there is a *Neural Network* widget present in [Orange 2](http://orange.biolab.si/orange2/).

Comment: @K3--rnc, It seems there is no Multi layer perceptron widget in Orange 2. Sometimes,I hope Orange goes  to direction of DeepLearning4J and implement DBN, CNN, RNN and extra.